# Create a list objects from request response

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to extract certain object when going through a response i'm getting from an API CALL.
Response =

```
[
    {'id': '2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61', 'name': 'Human', 'i18nNameKey': 'Blank space Blueprint', 'pluginClone': True
    },
    {'id': '99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369', 'name': 'Robot', 'i18nNameKey': 'Personal space Blueprint', 'pluginClone': True
    },
    {'id': 'bf40b0e5-f151-4df6-b305-4a91b4b7c1da', 'name': 'Dog', 'i18nNameKey': 'Game.blueprints.space.kb.name', 'pluginClone': True
    },
    {'id': '42868b38-b9f8-4540-ba26-0988e8a2e1f7', 'name': 'Bug', 'i18nNameKey': 'Game.blueprints.space.team.name', 'pluginClone': True
    },
    {'id': 'b23eb9fd-0106-452a-8cab-551ce3b45eb0', 'name': 'Cat', 'i18nNameKey': 'Game.blueprints.space.documentation.name', 'pluginClone': True
    },
    {'id': '67668d17-6c08-4c85-a6b6-3c1d6fb23000', 'name': 'Cat', 'i18nNameKey': 'Game.blueprints.space.sp.name', 'pluginClone': True,
    }
]
```

I need to regroup, the id and the name, at the moment i'm able to retrieve them but the response is not what i want t achieve
I'm getting a list of string , instead of a list of object, what i'm doing wrong ?

```
def listallCategories(self):
self.intentsResponseDict=[]
url = self.url
response = requests.get(url,auth=(self.user,self.password))
json_data = response.json()
#print(json_data)
for resp in json_data:
    self.intentsResponseDict.append(resp['id'])
    self.intentsResponseDict.append(resp['name'])
return self.intentsResponseDict
```

this is what i'm getting

```
['2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61', 'Human', '99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369', 'Robot', 'bf40b0e5-f151-4df6-b305-4a91b4b7c1da', 'Dog', '42868b38-b9f8-4540-ba26-0988e8a2e1f7', 'Bug', 'b23eb9fd-0106-452a-8cab-551ce3b45eb0', 'Cat', '67668d17-6c08-4c85-a6b6-3c1d6fb23000', 'Bird']
```

This is what i want id , name

```
[
    {'2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61', 'Human'
    },
    {'99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369', 'Robot'
    },
    {'bf40b0e5-f151-4df6-b305-4a91b4b7c1da', 'Dog'
    },
    {'42868b38-b9f8-4540-ba26-0988e8a2e1f7', 'Bug'
    },
    {'b23eb9fd-0106-452a-8cab-551ce3b45eb0', 'Cat'
    },
    {'67668d17-6c08-4c85-a6b6-3c1d6fb23000', 'Bird'
    }
]
```

Comment: Very confusing to have a list called 'intentsResponseDict', why don't you use a dict like the name suggests ?

Comment: Is this list of objects to be a set? or a list? you could just do `for resp in json_data: self.intentsResponseDict.append([resp['id'], resp['name']])` assuming you want a set not a list

Comment: Don't you just need to use `json_data` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resp` is probably like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61",
    "name": "Human",
    ... more fields ...
  },
  {
    "id": "99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369",
    "name": "Robot",
    ... more fields ...
  },
... more objects ...
]
```

The format that you want the data isn't a valid JSON, a better schema for that JSON may be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61",
    "name": "Human",
  },
  {
    "id": "99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369",
    "name": "Robot",
  },
... more objects ...
]
```

So, you are just picking `id` and `name` in the response

```
for resp in json_data:
    self.intentsResponseDict.append({
        "id": resp["id"],
        "name": resp["name"]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you show is a list of sets. Just build it:

```
...
for resp in json_data:
    self.intentsResponseDict.append({resp['id'], resp['name']})
...
```

Comment: Sometimes i'm getting the id first sometimes i'm getting the name first. it's not alway 
[{id,name},{id,name},{id,name}...]

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit - You're creating a list of sets, so the order of the elements in the set is irrelevant. Otherwise, don't make a list of sets.

Comment: @Sayse Is there a proper way to retrieve the data from the requests response properly ? maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit: You are experiencing the X-Y problem. You asked for a precise (but impossible) thing, without giving your real need nor enough context. Go back one step and say what the real problem is...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I updated my question hope, it's clear now

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit No it is not. You have been told that the order in a set is irrelevant, yet you insist in having both sets and order respect. Could you use tuples instead: `[
    ('2a15947c-8cdb-4f1d-a1cc-a8d76fd97d61', 'Human'
    ),
    ('99accff8-9e24-4c76-b21a-f12ef6572369', 'Robot'
    ), ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding both the ID and name to the end of a list

```
for resp in json_data:
    self.intentsResponseDict.append(resp['id']) # here is your issue
    self.intentsResponseDict.append(resp['name'])  # and here
return self.intentsResponseDict
```

If you want these values to stay together you would need to add them to the list together. e.g.

```
for resp in json_data:
    self.intentsResponseDict.append([resp['id'], resp['name']]) # to create list of lists
    # OR
    self.intentsResponseDict.append({resp['id'], resp['name']}) # to create list of dicts
return self.intentsResponseDict
```